# How to Organize an out of control table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

Hello and good morning.

I am working on a side project where I am adding an analytic board to an already existing app. The problem is that now the users table has over 400 columns. My question is that what's a better way of organizing this table such as splintering the table off into separate tables. How do you do that and how do you communicate the tables between the new tables?

Another concern is that If I separate the table will I still be able to save into it through the user model? I have code right now that says:

```
user.wallet += 100
user.save
```

If I separate wallet from user and link the two tables will I have to change this code. The reason I'm asking this is that there is a ton of code like this in the app.

Thank you so much if you can help me understanding how to organize a database. As a bonus if there is a book that talks about database organization can you recommend it to me (preferably one that is in rails).

Edit: Is there also a way to do all of this without loosing any data. For example transfer the data to a new column on the new table then destroying the old column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read about:

> Database Normalization

You'll get loads of hits when searching for that string and there are many books about database design covering that subject.

It is most likely, that this table of yours lacks normalization, but you have to see yourself!
Just to give an orientation - I would get a little anxious when dealing with a tenth of that number of columns. That saying, I clearly have to stress that there might be well normalized tables with 400 columns as well as sloppily created examples with just 10 columns.
Generally speaking, the probability of dealing with bad designed tables and hence facing trouble simply rises with the number of columns.

So take your time and if you find out, that users table needs normalization next step would indeed be to spread data over several tables. Because that clearly (and most likely even heavily) affects the coding of your application here is where you thoroughly have to balance pros and cons - simply impossible to judge that from far away.

Say, you have substantial problems (e.g. fierce performance problems - you wouldn't post it) that could be eased by normalization there are different approaches of how to split data. Here please read about:

> Cardinalities

Usually the new tables are linked by

> Foreign Keys

, identical data (like a user id) that appear in multiple tables and that are used to join them, that is.

And finally, yes, you can do that without losing data as the overall amount of information never changes when normalizing.
In case your last question was meant to be technical: There is no problem in reading data from one column and inserting them into a new one (of a new table). That has to happen in a certain order as foreign keys have to be filled before you can use them. See

> Referential Integrity

However, quite obvious: Deleting data and dropping columns interferes with the operability of your application. Good planning is due.

Comment: Thank you so much... there's so much to learn about this stuff (complete noob... I know). Time to hit the books! (I bought 
Database Design for Mere Mortals)